# Designing and simulating a common source amplifier circuit

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, design, simulation, spice

This is the problem:

[image]

And this is my design for R1 and R2:

[image]

So, using B2 Spice simulator I made this circuit according to the design:

[image]

Vin_ and Vout_ are voltmeters.

But the problem is that when I run the simulation, I get this graph:

[image]

Vin_ shows correct result.

Vout_ should be amplified by Av(=10) but I don't know why it is not in this graph !!

Please show me where the mistake is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the mosfet to work as an amplifier, it needs to be biased in the saturation region, ie Vgs needs to be > Vt (4.15V). And it needs to remain so irrespective of excursions of +/- 100mV of v in.